# jQuery or JS to trim characters from inside a span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove the end of some text within a span using jQuery or JS.

```
<h3 class="ms-standardheader ms-WPTitle">
    <a href="" tabindex="0" accesskey="W">
    <nobr>
        <span>Programs ‭[1]‬</span>
```

I have 15 titles that are generated like this in SharePoint - 5 Programs, 5 Clinical Services, and 5 Other Support. I want to remove the [x] from each of them, however this is auto generated by SharePoint because it doesn't like having titles of the same name.

I've tried iterations of:

```
$('.ms-WPTitle a nobr span').splice(0, -4);
```

I can't seem to get at the text within the span to trim it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.ms-WPTitle a nobr span').text(function(el, old){ 
  return old.slice(0, -4);
});
```

`.text()` accepts a function, which you can use to easily trim chars

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vhTuA/

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Unfortunately that ends up deleting all of the text from every span

Comment: @Gofdambi - sorry, use `slice` instead of `substr`

Comment: I ended up working it out.
    $(".ms-WPTitle span:first-child").each(function(e) {
        $(this).text($(this).text().split('[')[0]);
    });
I double checked you answer and it works with fewer lines than mine

Answer (score 1):

Since ahren has given one approach you can try this as well: you can also try

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/CCvPQ/2/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/CCvPQ/4/

API used:

- http://api.jquery.com/first/
- http://api.jquery.com/text/
- http://api.jquery.com/find/

Hope it fits the cause `:)`

**code**

```
jQuery.fn.justtext = function() {

    return $(this).children().find('span').text();

};

alert($('.ms-standardheader').justtext());
```

**using .first api**

http://jsfiddle.net/qRZe7/1/

```
jQuery.fn.justtext = function() {

    return $(this).children().find('span').first().text();

};

alert($('.ms-standardheader').justtext());
```